# Solr Regex based unknown parts of the query based on set conditions

Tags: solr

The idea is to get results based on unknown parts of the query based on set conditions.

I am using Solr 5 and trying a regex pattern with Query. The sample data is

```
123@0.com
```

I am trying this pattern `/1.{2}@0.com/`, this is not working so i tried  `/.*[0-9{3}].*@0.com/`

```
{x} represents the number of characters. (Replace x with a number)
The . represents a wildcard, this will fill in the space with any character
```

Example: a.

The both patterns didn't fill the needs.

Has anybody tried regex with Solr 5 and above?

Comment: What is the field type? A regex is applied towards the stored tokens as far as I remember, so unless `123@0.com` is stored as a single token, you won't get any matches

Comment: @MatsLindh field type is type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"

Comment: In that case a regex won't do any good, since each token probably will be `123`, `0`, `.com` - you can see what tokens are generated under the Analysis tab in the Solr web interface.

Comment: @MatsLindh You are right its three parts so there's no solution with type text_general?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. Use a `string` field to index the content (as an additional field if necessary) to use regex-es against the whole string.